# Exiting from a chunk when "." is encountered

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk, chunking

I want the chunker to consider each single line to make chunks using the grammar provided and for that I am considering `"."` to exit but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried `<\\.$>`
and `<[.]$>`

But it seem to have no effect while chunking.

```
def pos_tag(sentence):
tags = clf.predict([features(sentence, index) for index in range(len(sentence))])
return zip(sentence, tags)

a = list(pos_tag(word_tokenize("He worked quite well. I find him good.")))


    grammar = r""" ZZZZZZ:      
          {<PRP.>+<VB.>+<[.]$|.*>*<RB.>*}
          {<PRP.|NN.>+<RB.>+<VB.>?}
          {<JJ.>+<[.]$|.*>*<NN.|PRP.>+}
          {<NN.|PRP.>+<[.]$|.*>*<JJ.>+}
          {<RB.>*<[.]$|.*>*<NN.>*}
          {<DT|PRP.>?<JJ.>+<NN>+}      
    """
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

chunked = cp.parse(a)

z = []

for subtree in chunked.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'ZZZZZZ'):
    z.append(subtree)
```

After I print z I am getting output.

I am getting the entire input string as a chunk without it being split at `"."`.

The second last line basically is an adjective and any number of words till a noun is found or a full stop is encountered.

The <.*>* is making the entire input as single valid chunk where as it should have stopped at the next full stop.

Comment: What would you expect as output from the splitting of `grammar`? Because if you run `grammar.split('.')` it will return a list of the string chunks split at the `.`

Comment: I want the output with those particular PoS tags just limited to a sentence.

Comment: I guess the <.*>* is causing the chunker to accept everything as it is not stopping at a fullstop.

Comment: But it still isn’t clear to me what the output for `grammar` would look like. Please add the expected outcome

Comment: I would try and give an example: Input "He worked quite well. I find him good. is giving the entire string as a single chunk. If at all there is any chunk present it needs to consider the above string as two possible chunks as they are two separate sentences. Consider there is only one rule, the top one from above code so "He worked quite well" would be the only chunk.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Are you intending that `grammar` is a regex pattern? And that you are going to call `re.match(grammar, mystring)` or something? When you are talking about nouns and adjectives though, basic regex doesn't have the power to understand language semantics like that, so you would need to use something else.

Comment: I am using a pos tagger on the input string. Output of PoS tagger : [('He', 'PRP'), ('worked', 'VBD'), ('quite', 'NN'), ('well', 'RB'), ('.', '.'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('find', 'VB'), ('him', 'PRP'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]

Comment: So what should `z` actually be then, based on the input string above?

Comment: chunked contains the entire tagged input with the chunked part. Which is later on filtered so that it contains just the chunked part and stored in z. I can assure you this works fine. I still think the problem is arising due to <.*>* where I am not being able to break the chunks at "." hence "." generally being a wildcard character is accepting the entire remaining string as a valid expression.

Comment: Ok, but if you don't show *exactly* what you think you want the output (`z`?) to look like, then it is very difficult to see where your problem can be fixed.

Comment: due to rule 1: [Tree('ZZZZZZ', [('He', 'PRP'), ('worked', 'VBD'), ('quite', 'NN'), ('well', 'RB')])] Due to rule 4 [Tree('ZZZZZZ', [('I', 'PRP'), ('find', 'VB'), ('him', 'PRP'), ('good', 'JJ') ])]  So total actual output [Tree('ZZZZZZ', [('He', 'PRP'), ('worked', 'VBD'), ('quite', 'NN'), ('well', 'RB')])Tree('ZZZZZZ', [('I', 'PRP'), ('find', 'VB'), ('him', 'PRP'), ('good', 'JJ')])]

Comment: For simplicity [Tree(chunk[chunk content]),Tree(chunk[chunk content])] if say there are two valid chunks instead of what I am getting that is  [Tree(chunk[chunk content])]

Comment: So I don't believe this is an intended use case for chunking is it? It seems like you are wanting sentence tokenization, which you would want to do *before* you do any chunking? See [this example](https://pythonprogramming.net/chunking-nltk-tutorial/). What would be the purpose of not doing the sentence tokenization first?

Comment: I have been using the exact same tutorial and some others to get this output. The question is using regex to make a chunk stop at a full stop. Which is an intended use case as it associates parts of speech to other words limited to a sentences.

Comment: What tutorial? The one I linked is clearly tokenizing sentences before doing any chunking.

Comment: pos_tag() on the first line is a function which is doing the same thing

Comment: The same thing as what?? `pos_tag()` is nothing to do with sentences. It is simply tagging words, as defined by `word_tokenize`, but if you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662286/nltk-pos-tagger-looks-to-incorporate) you will see the intention is that you first split into sentences before you split into words.

Comment: It could work but why can't we just use a fullstop in RE as an end indicator? \\ allows us to do that as well as [ ] is what I have gathered from similar posts.

Comment: I don’t think that the `nltk.regexpparser` is exactly the same as standard regex...